# PHP Array and mySql insert

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, mysqli

I am posting an array which will look something like this `4, 6, 7`

I am having trouble inserting each of these values into an sql table though.

Here's what I have so far...

```
$a = array($_POST['newsletterArray']);
$mything = 32;

$values = array();
foreach($a as $key => $value) {
    $values[] = "('{$mything}', '{$value}')";
}
if(sizeof($values)) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO images (news_event_id, newsletter_id) VALUES ".implode(',', $values);
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
}
```

This code inserts the first record from the array but none of the subsequent records.

If I substitute `$_POST['newsletterArray']` with `4, 6, 7` it works fine so it seems this is where the problem is.

`newsletterArray` is a text input if that helps at all.

Comment: If I am not totally mistaken that first line will not produce an array the way you mention.

Comment: maybe not... that's why I'm asking where i'm going wrong.

Comment: Well, Why maybe? Dump the value in `$a` and have a look! I could imagine `$_POST['newsletterArray']` being an array itself, as it might be the result of checkboxes being posted as part of a form submission. In that case use `$a=$_POST['newsletterArray']`. Otherwise you get an array holding an array inside $a which does not make sense for your foreach loop. So, clearly the fist step: _what is the value of `$_POST['newsletterArray']`_?

Comment: The value of post array is exactly what i said it was... from a text input - not the best approach I'll be the first to admit, but it's the one I'm having to work with.

Comment: Please, for your own safety and job security, use [SQL placholders](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to do your [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). What you're doing here is reckless.

Comment: That means you have a text input field where you type in `4, 6, 7` and want to use that `string` as an array? That is something different. Your code gives you an array holding a single element of type `string`, so array("4, 6, 7"), that is completely different from array(4,6,7). Instead you have to 'explode' the string into separate elements and clear those afterwards: `$a=explode(',',$_POST['newsletterArray']);for($i=0; $i<count($a);$i++)$a[$i]=(integer)trim($a);`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have associative array here. Judged by what you have written, your $a is just a list like this

```
a = array(4,6,7);
```

So you need to treat it this way in the foreah

```
foreach($a as $value) {
    $values[] = "('{$mything}', '{$value}')";
}
```

This will do the work

Comment: Failing to escape when using `mysqli` is inexcusable.